# Uploading required HTML or JS in Apache Sling CMS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, sling

I wanted to upload html file which is created by me instead of html.html in Apache Sling CMS, can anyone help me out how to upload that
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44hO3.png

I have replaced html.html with my html but it didn't worked.

Thank you!!!